# How do I force a div to stretch to fit its content rather than making scrollbars?

Tags: css, html, overflow

I had a table in my application that could grow to ridiculous heights, so I added a wrapper `div` around it and set `overflow-y: auto` to get scrollbars. This unfortunately stopped the div from stretching it's width. Now it has scrollbars for both height and width. Setting `overflow-x: visible` doesn't even affect the result. I need the width to stretch since the content is of variable width.

Fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/SG8T9/3

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean but take a look here
http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

from that page:

> According to the spec ... some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’ ....

so `overflow-x: visible` becomes `overflow-x: auto`.

maybe you can make the container wide enough to hold the content, so it doesn't have to overflow.

Comment: Your link confirms that my shot at fixing the problem won't work. I'll have to come up with another one. I still need help with that though :-)

Comment: @Codemonkey can you give the outer div an explicit width? like this: `div#outer {width: 900px}` 
is the container element of the outer div wide enough? you could do this: `div#outer {width: 100%}`

Comment: No, the outer div should scale with the content. This is because the outer div is an inline-block and should wrap to the next line when the width reaches a certain point

Comment: Marking this answer as correct since the link explains how my desired result is impossible

Answer (score 0):

You must not define a width for your div, otherwise it will not overflow that width regardless of the overflow-x setting. Instead use min-width and max-width to set expansion values, then `overflow-x:visible;` should work fine.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shanethehat/SG8T9/

Note that the defined max-width must be at least as large as the width of the content plus the width of the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: I've edited your fiddle to display my problem. As you can see, a width  of the wrapper is not set, as it should scale with the content http://jsfiddle.net/SG8T9/3/